# CSS: How can I show identical elements in two columns, without spacing between the elements?

Tags: html, css

I have some HTML code that looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="element"> </div>
    <div class="element"> </div>
    <div class="element"> </div>
    <div class="element"> </div>
</div>
```

And I want to display it in a two-column layout, where each element is displayed directly underneath the one above. I've made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nvmcxjpL/1/) to show my current progress, but I can't figure out how to remove the white gaps between the elements. Is it at all possible, or do i need to change the HTML (I'd rather not)?

Answer (score 1):

An easy way would be to wrap each column items into separate divs. Your .box and .one, .two, .three css declarations are interfering.

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/grLyvomy/][1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a seperate div for each column (in your case two).

```css
.container{ 
    border: 1px black solid;
    width: 320px;
}
.clear{
    clear: both;
}
.leftColumn{
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
.rightColumn{
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
}

.box:nth-child(2n+1){
    background: green;    
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
.box:nth-child(2n){
    background: red;    
    border-bottom: 1px solid green;

}
.one{ height: 50px; }
.two { height: 80px; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="leftColumn">
        <div class="box one">first</div>
        <div class="box two">second</div>
        <div class="box three">third</div>
    </div>
    <div class="rightColumn">
        <div class="box else">first</div>
        <div class="box two">second</div>
        <div class="box three">third</div>
        <div class="box four">fourth</div>
        <div class="box one">last</div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nvmcxjpL/8/

Answer (score 0):

Try to change one and three divs height sum same as two by changing three div height 20px to 30px

```
.three {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 30px;  
}
```